# Change tab color based on cell vaule

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I am trying to change the tab color based on a cell value on an individual sheet.  I have multiple tabs.  The cell value that will determine whether or not it gets a color is a cell containing a date.

This is what I have- I can't get it to work.   Any suggestions?

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var first = ss.getSheetByName("3005");
  var second = ss.getSheetByName("3006");
   var third = ss.getSheetByName("3007");
    var fourth = ss.getSheetByName("3008");
 var cell1 = first.getRange("c26");
  var cell2 = second.getRange("c24");
   var cell3 = third.getRange("c24");
    var cell4 = fourth.getRange("c24");
 var cellContent1 = cell1.getValue();
  if (cellContent1 == "date") {
 first.setTabColor("#66FF00");
  }
  if (cellContent1 == 0) {
 first.setTabColor(null);}
  var cellContent2 = cell2.getValue();
  if (cellContent2 == "date") {
 second.setTabColor("#66FF00");
  }
  if (cellContent2 == 0) {
 second.setTabColor(null);}
 var cellContent3 = cell3.getValue();
  if (cellContent3 == "date") {
 third.setTabColor("#66FF00");
  }
  if (cellContent3 == 0) {
 third.setTabColor(null);}
var cellContent4 = cell4.getValue();
  if (cellContent4 == "date") {
 fourth.setTabColor("#66FF00");
  }
  if (cellContent4 == 0) {
 fourth.setTabColor(null);}}
```

If I tell it to change color based on a number it works fine - i.e.

```
 function onEdit(e) { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var first = ss.getSheetByName("3005"); 
var cell1 = first.getRange("i20"); 
var cellContent1 = cell1.getValue(); 
if (cellContent1 == 1) 
{ first.setTabColor("#66FF00"); } 
if (cellContent1 == 0) 
{ first.setTabColor(null);}}
```

Comment: This is the form I'm working with https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vKnsvoCITkQEuouYHr64uUS2_kPluKYFIKXyZBD_GrA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I [posted an answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173566) based on what I think you want to do.  If you edit the correct sheet and cell, it then tests if the value in the cell is a date. If so, it sets the tab color. If not, it clears the tab color. If there are other states that are relevant (e.g. not a date and also not a zero, please clarify).

Comment: What is the **purpose** of the tab color change?  I see that you have multiple `SERVICE DATE` fields in your sheet. Does only one matter?

Comment: Only the first date matters.  If the tab is green, it's been used.  No color= open to use

Comment: I assume that you will probably add additional tabs (order #) to the spreadsheet. Would it be better if the script dynamically retrieved the sheet names so the script doesn't need to be edited all the time? Maybe some logic like if the sheet name is a set of numbers and the edited cell is the one below *service date* in column C, then is it a date ...

Comment: Merged cells are problematic and best avoided unless necessary.  Given that you have merged rows 24 and 25 for C, D, E, and F, it would seem that unmerging them and instead changing the height of a single row to accept multi-line titles is more appropriate.  See `Copy of 3005`.  The description field could be a single cell in case you want to do anything with the data, and also to allow for line wrapping, etc.  `=today()`  will change every day so might not be a good way to determine the date.  Maybe add that to the script to populate that on first edit or something

Comment: Yes, I will be adding more tabs to the sheet.  C24 has a date picker.

Comment: THANK  YOU SO MUCH.  It does exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

## Script

I edited your script to add the date-test based on what I think you want to do:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const name = sheet.getName();
  const color = "66FF00";
  
  const cells = [ 
    { Sheet: "3005",  A1: "C26" },
    { Sheet: "3006",  A1: "C24" },
    { Sheet: "3007",  A1: "C24" },
    { Sheet: "3008",  A1: "C24" }
  ];
  
  let i = cells.findIndex(c => c.Sheet === name);
  
  if ((i > -1) && (cells[i].A1.indexOf(range.getA1Notation()) > -1)) {

    let tabColor = isDate(range.getValue()) ? color : null;
    
    sheet.setTabColor(tabColor);  

  }

}

function isDate(v) {
 
  return v.constructor === Date;
  
}
```

## Notes

1. To determine if the value `v` from Sheets is a date, you can use a function to return TRUE if it's a date object, otherwise FALSE:

   ```
   function isDate(v) {
     return v.constructor === Date;
   }
   ```
2. To check if the sheet name is in the array `cells` [findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp) returns either the index number associated with the sheet name or `-1`:

   ```
   let i = cells.findIndex(c => c.Sheet === name);
   ```
3. The first two T/F tests are designed to avoid processing further code unnecessarily. If the first fails the second isn't attempted `&&`:

   1. Is the sheet's name listed in `cells`?

      ```
      (i > -1)
      ```
   2. Is the cell's address listed for that sheet in `cells`?

      ```
      (cells[i].A1.indexOf(range.getA1Notation()) > -1)
      ```
   3. If both conditions #1 and #2 are true then set the `tabColor` to:

      1. `color` if the edited value **is** a date
      2. `null` if the edited value **is not** a date